# Haml::SyntaxError - Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %div and nested within it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

以下のhtmlをhamlで書きたいと思ってます。

html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    あいうえお
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
        あいうえお
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
        あいうえお
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

haml:

```
.row
  .col-sm-9 あいうえお
    .row
      .col-xs-8.col-sm-6 あいうえお
      .col-xs-4.col-sm-6 あいうえお
```

しかし、このようにhamlで書くとエラーが発生してしまいます。

> Haml::SyntaxError - Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %div and nested within it.

上記のようなhtmlにしたい場合、どうhamlを修正すればよろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  .col-sm-9 あいうえお
    .row
```

タグの中身は「タグのすぐ後ろ」か「より深いインデント」の**どちらか**に書く必要があり、併用はできません。エラーメッセージで言うところの `on the same line as %div` が `あいうえお` 、 `nested within it` が `.row` に対応しています。

この場合、両方ともインデントして記載すればいいでしょう。

```
  .col-sm-9
    あいうえお
    .row
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLKgVg

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-sm-9'>
    あいうえお
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-xs-8 col-sm-6'>あいうえお</div>
      <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-6'>あいうえお</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```